# JuliaDB groupby: mixing sum with constants

Tags: julia, juliadb

I want to sum the elements of a table grouped by a field and then divided by a constant: For example, I have a table with department and sells and I want to sum all the sells of each department and then divide by 100 (for example). That's the code:

```
groupby(@NT(sells_factor = sum/100),sells_table,:department; select = :package)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an anonymous function should work for you in one pass:

```
groupby(@NT(sells_factor = x -> sum(x)/100),sells_table, :department; select = :package)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd first calculate the sums and then divide them using map. See [https://juliacomputing.github.io/JuliaDB.jl/latest/api/#Base.map-Tuple{Any,IndexedTables.AbstractIndexedTable}](https://juliacomputing.github.io/JuliaDB.jl/latest/api/#Base.map-Tuple%7BAny,IndexedTables.AbstractIndexedTable%7D)

Comment: It works, but then you have to make a `pushcol `  to see the table with the new column that you computed before

Comment: Broken link may please be fixed!